# Определить "ближайший" тег input

Tags: jquery

Привет, есть такое чудо (самодельный инпут с вариантами):

```
    <div>
        <input id="select" value="click for variants" />
        <ul>
            <li onclick="$('#select').val(this.innerHTML);">value0</li>
            <li onclick="$('#select').val(this.innerHTML);">value1</li>
            <li onclick="$('#select').val(this.innerHTML);">value2</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

есть ли возможность как то находить input "универсально", а не по Id="select" как в данном коде? тк таких полей будет много, а прописывать id каждому не очень удобно, заранее спасибо за внимание,

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Yusm/

Comment: @Олег Б, если у Вас много таких списков, то имеет смысл сделать плагин, для более удобного подключения. Вот небольшой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/eauw4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пример с поправками](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/8Yusm/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input value="click for variants" />
    <ul>
        <li>value0</li>
        <li>value1</li>
        <li>value2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('ul').siblings('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

P.S. Удивительно - прописывать каждому элементу списка событие onclick - вам не облом, а id-шники для каждого input - это уже проблемка )))

Comment: Deonis вот смотрите, очень нравится ваша позиция отделять "мух от котлет". Будте добры, если подскажите логику "скрывния" меню через jquery? т.е. посути обработать клик "на пустом месте" и скрыть все 'ul'.> for example: http://jsfiddle.net/5rbB6/1/

Comment: @Олег Б, Дык оно ж у вас [было реализовано](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/8Yusm/3/) и без JS

Comment: Не работает там где нет transition (IE). ;(

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть в сторону [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). Получаем [такой результат](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5rbB6/2/).